# How to set linux nlog folder in asp.net core

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, nlog

I use NLog in my asp.net core 2.0 applications, and I want to deploy it to Ubuntu. I can find lots of threads and articles, but all of them are deploy in Windows.

My nlog.config snippet looks as below,

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="ownlog" fileName="${var:configDir}\nlog-own.log"
             layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|  ${message} ${exception}" />
```

and in my Startup.cs file, I set the configDir as below,

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["configDir"] = "\\var\\log";
```

It doesn't work. Anyone can help? How can I store the log file in \var\log folder?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to reverse the slashes, so they become unix-style: /var/log/nlog-own.log ? Have you tried to check file-permissions ? Have you checked NLog InternalLogger ? (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change your path from double backslash to a single slash. If you want to keep both environments, you can do something like this:

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
// use windows path
else
// use linux path
```

Comment: Please provide a proper example. This code just shows how to get os platform in .net core, not how to use that with nlog.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the NLog default example, and replacing the backward slashes `\` with forward slashes `/` in `nlog.config` worked both in windows and linux docker. `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` to get my `{basedir}` works on both as well.

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${basedir}/logs/all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

```cs
var name = "all";
var entryDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var baseDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(entryDir, @"logs"));
var logFilePath = baseDir.GetFiles()
                    .Where(f => f.Name.Contains(name))
                    .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                    .First();
```